# Is there any way to configure trac to use a custom mailing tool?

Tags: email, com, bug-tracking, trac

Is there any way trac could be made to work with a custom mail tool?

For example, imagine a command line script which takes all of it's arguments from it's command line arguments:

```
script -s sender -t title -to whomever@mail.com -b body
```

The tool is configured to use COM for email sending, and I think it would be impossible to define an SMTP server for trac to use.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way trac could be made to work with a custom mail tool?

I don't know, but if there is one, it's probably to be found on [**Trac-Hacks.org**](http://www.trac-hacks.org).

Interesting candidates (I have not checked whether they can use alternative mailers, but if they don't, it might be easy to achieve):

- [**WikiNotification**](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiNotificationPlugin)
- [**AnnouncerPlugin**](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AnnouncerPlugin)